# unable to access application from kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have created a simple php application trying to access from kubernetes cluster but I am unable access the application

my deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rajendar38/myhtmlapp
        name: myhtmlapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

my service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myhtmlapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort

rajendar@HP-EliteBook:~/Desktop/work$ kubectl get services
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        26h
my-service    ClusterIP   10.102.235.244   <none>        4000/TCP       24h
php-service   NodePort    10.110.73.30     <none>        80:31000/TCP   22m
```

I am using minikube for this application 
when I am trying to connect to http:127.0.0.1:31000/test.html
I unable to connect to application

Thanks

Rajendar

Comment: How do you run the php application? Is it really listening to port 80 in the container? Did you test it with pure docker on a local machine?

Comment: docker run -d -p 4000:80 rajendar38/myhtmlapp  , I am able to run docker image in this way able to access it as well

Comment: Could you add the error message when trying to access the application?

Comment: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:31000.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: my Image is  there in the docker hub , you can give a try as well .docker pull rajendar38/myhtmlapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minikube is using a virtual machine to provide the single node cluster.
When exposing a NodePort service it is local from the perspective of the VM, which is usually not the same as your local machine.

Use `minikube ip` to determine the IP of the machine and use that IP instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to access NodePort services on the minikube cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The target port and port are same 80 therefore the services is using port 80 for both 
try

```
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

As say @Thomas, you must find the IP of the VM with:

```
minikube ip
```

and after launch the service with this IP and the port 31000, in your case.